# Iterate Select option of HTML using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to add a select option from values from `1920` to `2015`. I know how to add it using option tag. But is there any other way to make loops from `1920` to `2015` using jquery? I have tried a code but not working. My code is as follows

```
<select id="selectid"  class="form-control"  name="batch" value="<?php echo set_value('batch'); ?>" > 
            <option>
            </option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">

  for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    $("#selectid").append("<option>" + i + "</option>");
} 
</script>
```

Comment: your code works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/7zLy1ryx/  just change to `for(i=1920; i<2015;i++)`

Comment: All in years , same code => http://jsfiddle.net/7zLy1ryx/2/

Comment: I had tried it. But the select doesn't shows any values. that's why I asked it again here... Kindly help me.

Comment: try wrapping it in `$(function(){/* code here */})` and make sure jquery.js script tag is included before your code

Comment: Oh god It worked inside a function.. Obne more query, How to give a default value? Say i want to show 1920 by default...

Comment: OK..so what was happening is you were calling the code before the element existed. See http://api.jquery.com/ready/ Now to add default use `$("#selectid").val(1920)` after the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the javascript as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
              $(function(){       
  for(i=1920; i<2015; i++){
    $("#selectid").append("<option>" + i + "</option>");
} $("#selectid").val(1920)})
  </script>
```

HTML part is as below

```
 <select id="selectid"  class="form-control"  name="batch" value="<?php echo set_value('batch'); ?>" > 
              <option>
              </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

html :

```
<select name="yearpicker" id="yearpicker"></select>
```

scripts :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var now = new Date();
for (i = 1920; i <= now.getFullYear(); i++)
{
    $('#yearpicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
}
})
```

have look at [this live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b915rud9/1/)